What is the of non-analyticity in deriving geometric optics from electromagnetic waves? (Relation of classical limit of QM)
In chapter 2 of Padmanabhan's Sleeping Beauties in Theoretical Physics, "The Emergence of Classical Physics", the author shows how that quantum mechanics produces the classical limit in the $\hbar \to 0$ limit, in part because the phase of the quantum amplitude is non-analytic in $\hbar$.
The author then makes the following statement between equations (2.8) and (2.9):

The reason essentially has to do with the fact that -- in proceeding from quantum physics to classical physics -- we are doing something analogous to obtaining ray optics from electromagnetic waves. One knows that this can come about only when the phase of the wave is non-analytic in the expansion parameter -- which is precisely the wavelength in the case of light propagation.

I do not fully appreciate the mathematical or physical significance of the phase being non-analytic in the transition from electromagnetic waves to ray/geometric optics. Is there a direct way to see this?
References to textbooks or lectures are appreciated as this likely points to a bigger gap in my understanding.

This is just the saddle point approximation of the path integral: if $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, only when the action does not vary the exponential stay still, while every (even small) variation of the action leads to highly oscillatory behavior. When integrating along all paths (of configurations for a field), the oscillations cancel out while the on-shell action is selected. Non-analyticity means that $\hbar$ is in the denominator of the exponent.

Ah, thank you @JeanbaptisteRoux. This addresses my question. If you transfer this to an answer I'd be happy to give you credit for an accepted answer.

I think I am often confused when authors point out singular points as non-analyticities. While the statement is true, I find myself wondering if they are implicitly referencing something like a contour integral around the singularity. Instead, I now understand that this is "just" steepest descent.
